# Saving tensorflow model in Databricks

Tags: python, tensorflow, databricks

is there any way how to save tensorflow model in Databricks.  Im using classical aproach like in Spyder:
`model.save('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/mymodel.h5')`  Unfortunately  Im still getting OOM (Out of memory error).  Exactly The error is:  *ConnectException error: This is often caused by an OOM error that causes the connection to the Python REPL to be closed. Check your query's memory usage.*
Thank you for your comments.
BR
Tomas

Comment: Hey there, please share with us the full Error message you are seeing and the code you are trying to run. This will help us to help you better :)

Comment: Hi, Kevin  Thank you for readin. the error is simple:  "ConnectException error: This is often caused by an OOM error that causes the connection to the Python REPL to be closed. Check your query's memory usage."